# How can I wait for an async method without a callback in ObjC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I have a method of the following type:

```
- (void)performFoo:(int)bar;
```

which internally does a dispatch call onto a background thread which then enqueues an animation onto the main thread to update `bar`. There is no callback as shown above to capture that it is completed. I am trying to write the following code in a test:

```
- (void)testFoo {
  [Klass performFoo:2];

  XCTAssertTrue([Klass barValue], 2);
}
```

Naturally, this assert will either fail or flake since the test immediately goes to the next line since `performFoo:` returns immediately but has not updated the `barValue`. What is the best strategy that you can recommend to wait / hook till `bar` is finished considering that I cannot change the code for `performFoo:`.

Naturally, I can try [NSRunloop runUntilDate:] to just spin the runloop for some time. However, this is not optimal since it's a timed wait every time and can be too much or insufficient. Any KVO technique or so you would recommend?

Comment: Your only possible approach is to wait for some period of time and check the result.  The function is not really testable as written

Comment: Thanks, yeah unfortunately that seems like the only way at the moment.

Comment: `animation onto the main thread to update bar` what kind of animation do you mean? If you interact with UI elements (and this is an integration UI test), you can rely on state of the UI component updated. For pure `int` there are no built-in functions with such a functionality